# Model derivative: translation stops at 50%, never fails, never completes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a following scenario, 2 revit files, ModelA.rvt and ModelB.rvt. They are cross-referenced together, zipped and uploaded twice under diferrent object key (ModelA.zip, ModelB.zip). ZIP files are identical, very small(4MB) and containing both files. They both are uploaded succesfuly in a loop using:

> PUT https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName

Files are overwritten with token scope data:write and a post job called with x-ads-force = true in case of model update. Then I call the POST JOB 2x in a loop, once with ModelA.rvt as rootFilename for ModelA.zip and secondly with ModelB.rvt for ModelB.zip. Both post jobs are done sucesfully.

Right after I am getting manifest for both zip files each 10 secs. ModelB.zip is translated 100% in a few secs, but ModelA.zip never finishes (few hours so far), just hangs for no reason.  On friday I thought that is just temporary issue, but no it still lasts.

I tried this scenario 3x times, each time with different set of files today and 3 days back. Same result. This one is the easiest one and they are all already present on the cloud. Still have no idea what is going on.

When I list bucket objects, zip files are never present. Another weird thing. Other files with non-zip extension are.

Does anyone have a clue what is causing this, what could be possible workaround? That is serious issue, because it corrupts usability and reliability of the whole API.

Answer (score 0):

The linked revit files need to be in one zipfile with the new v2 API. See this post for more details: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/translate-referenced-files-by-derivative-api.html

Comment: I think you did not understand well what I wrote in my question. Both files are in one zip file. And that zip file is uploaded twice under diferrent object key so both files could be translated diferrently.

Comment: do you got the urn for both, so we can ask our QA department to take a look?

Comment: This issue lasted for almost 4 days and now looks it vanished so translation completes without struggle but without proper investigation of what happened this can happen to anybody in the future again.